# How can warm start a method in TwinCAT?

Tags: twincat, st, iec61131-3

One of the features of the method based on the definition of Beckoff [site](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/9007201785048459-2.html&id=) is that:

> All data of a method are temporary and are only valid while the method
> is executed (stack variables). This means that TwinCAT re-initializes
> all variables and function blocks, which you have declared in a
> method, with each call of the method.

Is there any way to use a method in the plc loop as `warm start!`

it means that we use the method without re_initializing and method declare variations run just once at the first time we call it and the rest of the time that is called the variables retain their own values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible through `VAR_INST` or `VAR_STAT`.
Just declare your variables as `VAR_INST/VAR_STAT` instead, then they will retain their values between the calls.

`VAR_INST` means it will be unique for every instantiation of the function block of where the method resides, while `VAR_STAT` will act as a static/global (all instances will point to the same memory location).

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2528798091.html&id=

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2528787339.html&id=